# onblur event doesn't work if user enter value in textfield and directly press browser refresh button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have **ajax** generated input field

```
<input type="text" value="naeem" onblur="updateAttendee(1)" id="first_name_1" name="first_name_1" placeholder="First Name">
```

onblur works fine when user input data and click anywhere outside the input field, but it doesn't work if user enter value and directly press browser refresh button

my updateAttendee() function:

```
function updateAttendee(attendee_id) {

    var first_name  = $("#first_name_"+attendee_id).val();
    var last_name       = $("#last_name_"+attendee_id).val();
    var email           = $("#email_"+attendee_id).val();



     $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              data: "attendee_id="+attendee_id+"&first_name="+first_name+"&last_name="+last_name+"&email="+email,
              url: "<?php echo $registry->getObject('url')->getEventUrl();?>index.php?mod=eventsiteAjax&func=ajaxUpdateAttendee",
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data) {

                if(data['status'] == '1') {

                        $("#div_attendees").append(data['attendee_box']);
                  //success 
                } else {
                    // alert(data['error']);

                }


              }
        });
}
```

Comment: i don't want onKeyUp function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First maintain one flag for input focus and blur

```
$("#first_name_1").focus(function() {
    $(this).data('flag', 1);
});

$("#first_name_1").blur(function() {
    $(this).data('flag', 0);
});
```

Then, manually trigger blur event for input box on window unload if blur was not already triggered after focusing.

```
$( window ).bind("beforeunload", function() {
    if($("#first_name_1").data('flag') == 1){
        $("#first_name_1").trigger('blur');
    }
});
```

Comment: console is giving me this error NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: